# What's the difference between a non-unmanaged type and a managed type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, unmanaged, managed

When I wrote the following snippet for experimenting purposes, it raised the hover-error (see screenshot):

> Cannot declare pointer to non-unmanaged type 'dynamic'

The snippet:

```
dynamic* pointerToDynamic = &fields;
```

While the code is clearly not allowed (you cannot take the address of a managed type), it raised with me the question: what is a **non-unmanaged type** and how is it different to a managed type? Or is it just Visual Studio trying to be funny?

[image]

Comment: Clearly a non-unmanaged type is a non-non-non-unmanaged type. Mmmm.

Comment: Don't read too much into a clumsy error message.  The C# binder simply doesn't support pointers.

Comment: There is no difference. The wording is simply due to the expected behavior. "Pointers are for unmanaged type. This is not one of those. It is a non-unmanaged type." The error is not that fields is managed, it's that fields is *not unmanaged*, even though those two phrases mean the same thing.

Comment: Just remember: If a program wants to be told to go left, and you tell it to go right, it can give you a non-left error.

Comment: @JustinTime, funny point, but the analogy here would be, "if the program tells you _not_ to go left, and you go left, it gives you an un-not-left error" ;))))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>There is a difference between unmanaged and non-managed pointers.</strike>

A managed *pointer* is a handle to an object on the managed heap, and AFAIK is available in managed C++ only. It is equivalent of C# *reference* to an object. Unmanaged pointer, on the other hand, is equivalent of a traditional C-style pointer, i.e. address of a memory location; C# provides unary `&` operator, `fixed` keyword and `unsafe` context for that.

You are trying to get a pointer to a managed field (`dynamic` is actually `System.Object` is disguise), while C# allows pointers to unmanaged objects only, hence the wording: your type is non-unmanaged.

A bit more on this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxx6f46y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

**Update:** to make it more clear, managed C++ supports classic C-style *pointers* and *references*. But to keep C++ terminology consistent, they are called *unmanaged* and *managed* **pointers**, correspondingly. C# also supports pointers (explicitly in `unsafe` context) and references (implicitly whenever objects of reference types are involved), but the latter is **not** called "managed pointers", they are just references.

To sum up: in C++ there are unmanaged and managed pointers, in C# - unmanaged pointers and references.

Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: That makes more sense in light of the error. I never realized unmanaged and non-managed were different things (and it seems you only got to explain the difference between managed/unmanaged pointers, typo?). But considering your last paragraph, that seems a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @Abel: I updated my answer, sorry if it was not clear. Maybe it's a bit better now.

Comment: I'm afraid you repeated what you already said ;). In your first line you refer to difference between **un** managed and **non-** managed pointers. The latter is then not mentioned in your text anymore. I'm aware of the difference between (un)managed pointers.

Comment: @Abel: Oh, now I understand, thanks. The phrase was indeed misleading.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create a pointer to a managed type. While int, double, etc are managed, they have unmanaged counterparts.

So what **non-unmanaged type** really means is the **managed type**.

The problem here is that the managed type since is sitting on the heap, you cannot get a pointer to. You can get a pointer using **fixed** keyword but that is mainly for arrays.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, thanks. What I was really curious about is the wording here. Why would IntelliSense call it a non-unmanaged type, when it means a managed type? In all other related errors, it is simply called a managed type. Is there really no difference? Semantically: Clean, Unclean and Non-unclean are all different. Non-unmanaged?