# Managed Types C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a non-unmanaged type and a managed type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941320/whats-the-difference-between-a-non-unmanaged-type-and-a-managed-type)

I was recently working on an application in C++ and I came across something called managed types, native types, marshaling etc. I am not quite sure what these terms mean. From what I have been reading, it seems that we have managed types in c++ to allow access to some .Net features (.Net native types) and we use marshaling to convert from managed types to native types (vice versa). Am I correct? thanks~

Comment: @Zeta: No, that other question is about confusion with the term 'non-unmanged type' in an error message rather than what managed types are.

Answer (score 1):

Managed C++ was/is a Microsoft creation.  Applications developed using the managed C++ framework operate within a virtual-machine environment the same way that .NET applications do.  This provides facility such as more run-time checking, memory allocation.  Also, the VM provided garbage collection just like .NET does for C#.  The limitation with the managed framework is that it the VM did not support multiple inheritance (C# does not support multiple inheritance).  Therefore managed C++ development was restricted.
Marshaling is also called serialisation where objects are converted to other "simple" types for transmitting to other processes or machines via RPCs.